# How to subtract date/time in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date

I have a field at a grid containing date/time and I need to know the difference between that and the current date/time. What could be the best way of doing so?

The dates are stored like `"2011-02-07 15:13:06"`.

Comment: What's the format of the date/time?

Comment: it's stored like that "2011-02-07 15:13:06"

Comment: This is not a duplicate. It has a different solution and is explained much better. It also has better search rank.

Answer (score 279, accepted):

This will give you the difference between two dates, in milliseconds

```
var diff = Math.abs(date1 - date2);
```

In your example, it'd be

```
var diff = Math.abs(new Date() - compareDate);
```

You need to make sure that `compareDate` is a valid `Date` object.

Something like this will probably work for you

```
var diff = Math.abs(new Date() - new Date(dateStr.replace(/-/g,'/')));
```

i.e. turning `"2011-02-07 15:13:06"` into `new Date('2011/02/07 15:13:06')`, which is a format the `Date` constructor can comprehend.

Comment: this ignores DTS handling for local timezone (works well with UTC)

Comment: in TypeScript I get a tslint error when I try to do this: var diff = Math.abs(new Date() - compareDate);

Comment: @Ethan: It does work. The time _should_ be added. The difference between 1980/1/1 and 1960/1/1 is the ten years between epoch and 1980, _plus_ the 10 years between 1960 and epoch. The difference between 1980/1/1 and 1975/1/1 on the other hand is the ten years between epoch and 1980, _minus_ the 5 years between 1975 and epoch. Both scenarios covered.

Comment: @DavidHedlund Yup, you're totally right. Brain fart on my end; deleted the comment.

Comment: this will give a wrong result if you are on daylight savings

Comment: `var d = new Date(); 
                                                               var start = new Date(d.setDate(d.getDate() - 7)) ;                $("#txtFromDate").attr("value", start.toISOString().substring(0, 10).replaceAll("-", "/"));`

Answer (score 56):

You can just substract two date objects.

```
var d1 = new Date(); //"now"
var d2 = new Date("2011/02/01");  // some date
var diff = Math.abs(d1-d2);  // difference in milliseconds
```

Comment: This won't work if d2 is before 1970; in that case, its timestamp in milliseconds will be negative, and the time between the unix epoch and d2 will actually get added to d1.

Comment: @Ethan Yes it will get added, that's the point. The difference between 3 and -3 is 6, `3 - (-3) ==  3 + 3 == 6`

Comment: `(new Date("1970/01/02") - new Date("1969/12/29"))  /1000/60/60/24 === 4`

Answer (score 19):

You can use `getTime()` method to convert the `Date` to the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970. Then you can easy do any arithmetic operations with the dates. Of course you can convert the number back to the `Date` with `setTime()`. See [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20110323231740/http://www.comptechdoc.org/independent/web/cgi/javamanual/javadate.html) an example.

Answer (score 19):

If you wish to get difference in wall clock time, for local timezone and with day-light saving awareness.

```
Date.prototype.diffDays = function (date: Date): number {

    var utcThis = Date.UTC(this.getFullYear(), this.getMonth(), this.getDate(), this.getHours(), this.getMinutes(), this.getSeconds(), this.getMilliseconds());
    var utcOther = Date.UTC(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate(), date.getHours(), date.getMinutes(), date.getSeconds(), date.getMilliseconds());

    return (utcThis - utcOther) / 86400000;
};
```

Test

```
it('diffDays - Czech DST', function () {
    // expect this to parse as local time
    // with Czech calendar DST change happened 2012-03-25 02:00
    var pre = new Date('2012/03/24 03:04:05');
    var post = new Date('2012/03/27 03:04:05');

    // regardless DST, you still wish to see 3 days
    expect(pre.diffDays(post)).toEqual(-3);
});
```

Diff minutes or seconds is in same fashion.

Comment: Brilliant answer, I was searching the whole web for a solution to the daylight saving issue and at last, you came by!

Answer (score 18):

Unless you are subtracting dates on same browser client and don't care about edge cases like day light saving time changes, you are probably better off using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) which offers powerful localized APIs. For example, this is what I have in my utils.js:

```
subtractDates: function(date1, date2) {
    return moment.subtract(date1, date2).milliseconds();
},
millisecondsSince: function(dateSince) {
    return moment().subtract(dateSince).milliseconds();
},
```

Comment: 6 years later, moment.js is considered far too bloated and overweight for its uses with dates. Consider this article and use some alternatives - https://dev.to/aminnairi/you-probably-don-t-need-moment-js-493m