# Creating a Script To Increase Numbers On Website

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

We have a website, on the front page we show "Parcels Shipped", we'd love the numbers to updated via a formula - i.e. we shipped 34,502,233 parcels in 2014... We show a static stat.... But we'd love to have the numbers increased via a formula that increases the number by the second/minute

Thanks for all the replies guys - So we current have this: gyazo.com/d421a3675884e2610d368c9e60e8acca

we want it to increase around 76 times per minute.... so a rotating number basically - i've no idea how to achieve this. (left number) & We want it to increase around 43 times per minute for middle number

Does anyone know where I can find this sort of trick?

Comment: Do you want it to be an actual number? If so you will need to use a server side language.

Comment: You just need a formula based on time and use JS to get the time and update the number every second

Comment: How many packages per second should it increase?

Comment: Thanks for all the replies guys - So we current have this: https://gyazo.com/d421a3675884e2610d368c9e60e8acca But we want it to increase around 2 every 15 seconds

Comment: Left and middle numbers should both increase by 2 every 15 seconds?

Comment: Sorry - we want it to increase around 76 times per minute.... so a rotating number basically - i've no idea how to achieve this. (left number)

Comment: We want it to increase around 43 times per minute for middle number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This achieves your desired functionality using `setInterval()` to fire a function that checks to see how long it's been since today. Then, multiplying by the increase you mentioned in the comments and adding it to the numbers in your screenshot.

**JS:**

```
function numberWithCommas(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}

function timeSince() {
    var prevTime = new Date(2015,8,8,0,0);
    var thisTime = new Date();
    return (thisTime.getTime() - prevTime.getTime()) / 1000;
}

function parcelCount() {
    var secDiff = timeSince();

    var leftNum = document.getElementById("left");
    var midNum = document.getElementById("mid");
    var leftNumCount = Math.round(((76/60) * secDiff) + 40093794);
    var midNumCount = Math.round(((43/60) * secDiff) + 22874098);

    leftNum.innerHTML = numberWithCommas(leftNumCount);
    midNum.innerHTML = numberWithCommas(midNumCount);
}
parcelCount();
setInterval(parcelCount, 1000);
```

**HTML:**

```
<h3>Left</h3>
<span id="left"></span>

<h3>Mid</h3>
<span id="mid"></span>
```

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hopkins_matt/513ng07d/

Used info from these answers to build this:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/2901298/4556503
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/6636639/4556503

Comment: Perfect Matt- many thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `setInterval` with the increasing function as 1st argument and ms as the 2nd one.

```
var el = document.getElementById('counter')
var x = 0
window.setInterval(function(){
  el.value = formula(++x)
}, 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the increase is completly random, just a "front-end design stuff" (sorry, guys), you can use `setInverval()` from Javascript.

It works this way:
every **_s** ms, the function will be called. If you have an increase factor, like a global constant you could do something like:

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById("myId");
var _mseconds = 1500; // mileseconds
var incFactor = 150;
var handlerInt = setInverval(function() {
 myDiv.innerHTML = incFactor+incFactor; // you can use Math.Random() or something, instead
}, _mseconds);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) - So we current have this: gyazo.com/d421a3675884e2610d368c9e60e8acca

we want it to increase around 76 times per minute.... so a rotating number basically - i've no idea how to achieve this. (left number) & We want it to increase around 43 times per minute for middle number

Comment: @DanHawkins well, first you would need not to use an image - `divs`, instead. The document.getElementById(id) is something you might wanna have a look: you're certainly use! You can create two variables with different increase factors (As far I've seen, constant factors: 76 and 43).
Each `setInverval()` must have a handler, so you can mess with them when needed. The seconds argument is in ms, so per minute 60000 would fit.

Comment: TL;DR; you should replace the `<img>` with at least two `<div>`, with unique IDs, then use `setInverval()` with the apropriate values (which you already have in mind!) :)

Comment: Don't worry about the image, that was just to show the stats :) they are text in div's - I'll take a look at the getElementById :) Many thanks for pointing me in the right direction, Would this be a permanent change to the number - or would this only apply for each time the page is loaded? 

Thanks @lockedz 

Dan

Comment: @DanHawkins the initial number would be constant... unless you created a range (just to look different each time) of a randomic set of numbers, then they would always show different initial numbers but still the same increase factor. The only problem I see with this approach is that sometime, within the range [x...y...z], x < y < z, you could get a z as an initial number and next time page is reloaded, boom, you get an x. That could be odd.