# Sort Array by ISO 8601 date

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, iso8601

How can I sort this array by date (ISO 8601)?

```js
var myArray = new Array();

myArray[0] = { name:'oldest', date:'2007-01-17T08:00:00Z' }
myArray[1] = { name:'newest', date:'2011-01-28T08:00:00Z' }
myArray[2] = { name:'old',    date:'2009-11-25T08:00:00Z' }
```

**Playground:**
https://jsfiddle.net/4tUZt/

Comment: Seems to me the date would sort alphabetically too

Comment: A lot of people are suggesting `Date.parse` but it doesn't give consistent results http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802461/javascript-which-browsers-support-parsing-of-iso-8601-date-string-with-date-par

Answer (score 129, accepted):

## Sort Lexicographically:

As @kdbanman points out, [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)<sup>See *General principles*</sup> was designed for lexicographical sort. As such the ISO8601 string representation can be sorted like any other string, and this will give the expected order.

```
'2007-01-17T08:00:00Z' < '2008-01-17T08:00:00Z' === true
```

So you would implement:

```
var myArray = [
    { name:'oldest', date:'2007-01-17T08:00:00Z' },
    { name:'newest', date:'2011-01-28T08:00:00Z' },
    { name:'old',    date:'2009-11-25T08:00:00Z' }
];

myArray.sort(function(a, b) {
    return (a.date < b.date) ? -1 : ((a.date > b.date) ? 1 : 0);
});
```

---

## Sort using JavaScript Date:

*Older versions of WebKit and Internet Explorer do not support ISO 8601 dates, so you have to make a compatible date. It is supported by FireFox, and modern WebKit though* See here for more information about Date.parse support [JavaScript: Which browsers support parsing of ISO-8601 Date String with Date.parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802461/javascript-which-browsers-support-parsing-of-iso-8601-date-string-with-date-par)

Here is a very good article for creating a Javascript ISO 8601 compatible date, which you can then sort like regular javascript dates.

[http://webcloud.se/log/JavaScript-and-ISO-8601/](https://web.archive.org/web/20121114064823/http://webcloud.se/log/JavaScript-and-ISO-8601/)

```
Date.prototype.setISO8601 = function (string) {
    var regexp = "([0-9]{4})(-([0-9]{2})(-([0-9]{2})" +
    "(T([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})(:([0-9]{2})(\.([0-9]+))?)?" +
    "(Z|(([-+])([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})))?)?)?)?";
    var d = string.match(new RegExp(regexp));

    var offset = 0;
    var date = new Date(d[1], 0, 1);

    if (d[3]) { date.setMonth(d[3] - 1); }
    if (d[5]) { date.setDate(d[5]); }
    if (d[7]) { date.setHours(d[7]); }
    if (d[8]) { date.setMinutes(d[8]); }
    if (d[10]) { date.setSeconds(d[10]); }
    if (d[12]) { date.setMilliseconds(Number("0." + d[12]) * 1000); }
    if (d[14]) {
        offset = (Number(d[16]) * 60) + Number(d[17]);
        offset *= ((d[15] == '-') ? 1 : -1);
    }

    offset -= date.getTimezoneOffset();
    time = (Number(date) + (offset * 60 * 1000));
    this.setTime(Number(time));
}
```

Usage:

```
console.log(myArray.sort(sortByDate));  

function sortByDate( obj1, obj2 ) {
    var date1 = (new Date()).setISO8601(obj1.date);
    var date2 = (new Date()).setISO8601(obj2.date);
    return date2 > date1 ? 1 : -1;
}
```

Updated usage to include sorting technique credit @nbrooks

Comment: I found that returning this at the bottom of

`Date.prototype.setISO8601 = function (string) {
    ...
    return this;

}`

was necessary to make this work...

Comment: This may be complete, but it's unnecessary.  **ISO8601 is [designed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#General_principles) for lexicographical sort, so just `'2007-01-17T08:00:00Z' < '2008-01-17T08:00:00Z'  ===  true`**

Comment: @kdbanman Thanks, good to know. I've updated the answer to include this.

Comment: Careful, this answer is not fully correct. As pointed out by @icoum below lexicographical sort does not work in case your ISO8601 date strings contain a time zone offset or - less common - a negative year. So in case you are not 100% sure all your dates are given in universal time you should definitely create date objects from your iso strings first and then compare the date objects.

Comment: TIL! This is smart

Answer (score 39):

You can avoid creating of dates and by using the built–in lexicographic compare function [*String.prototype.localeCompare*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare), rather than the `?:` compound operator or other expressions:

```js
var myArray = [
  {name: 'oldest', date: '2007-01-17T08:00:00Z'},
  {name: 'newest', date: '2011-01-28T08:00:00Z'},
  {name: 'old', date: '2009-11-25T08:00:00Z'}
];

// Oldest first
console.log(
  myArray.sort((a, b) => a.date.localeCompare(b.date))
);

// Newest first
console.log(
  myArray.sort((a, b) => -a.date.localeCompare(b.date))
);
```

Answer (score 12):

Be careful, the accepted answer now advises to sort our dates lexicographically.

However, **this will only work if all your strings use the 'Z' or '+00' timezone** (= UTC).
Date strings ending with 'Z' do satisfy ISO8601 standard, but all ISO8601 do not end with 'Z'.

Thus, to be fully ISO8601 compliant, you need to parse your strings with some Date library (e.g. [Javascript Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) or [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)), and compare these objects.
For this part, you can check Scott's answer that also covers browsers incompatible with ISO8601.

My simple example with Javascript Date (works on any not-too-old browser) :

```
var myArray = [
    { name:'oldest', date:'2007-01-17T08:00:00Z' },
    { name:'newest', date:'2011-01-28T08:00:00+0100' },
    { name:'old',    date:'2009-11-25T08:00:00-0100' }
];

myArray.sort(function(a, b) {
    return new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date);
});
```

Downside : This is slower than just comparing strings lexicographically.

More info about ISO8601 standard : [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_offsets_from_UTC).

Comment: Hi, I have to disagree. For example, in a web app, you could compare some date you got from an API, and some date you just picked in the web app. The second one would surely use the computer's local time zone, which could be different from the API's.
You could also compare dates you got from 2 different APIs that use different time zones.

Comment: The sort function needs to return 1, -1, or 0. I don't see how that can work here by subtracting new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date)

Comment: Hello !
Actually, the function given to sort as an argument does not have to return precisely -1 or 1.
Returning any negative value does the same as returning -1. Same for positve values and 1. You can check the doc page for JS sort function : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort
Also, this all works because subtracting two JS Date objects returns the difference between them in milliseconds : https://stackoverflow.com/a/4944782/9903390
Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 6):

I'd go with this:

```js
const myArray = new Array();

myArray[0] = { name:'oldest', date:'2007-01-17T08:00:00Z' }
myArray[1] = { name:'newest', date:'2011-01-28T08:00:00Z' }
myArray[2] = { name:'old',    date:'2009-11-25T08:00:00Z' }

function byDate (a, b) {
    if (a.date < b.date) return -1; 
    if (a.date > b.date) return 1; 
    return 0;  
}

const newArray = myArray.sort(byDate);


console.clear();
console.dir(myArray);
console.dir(newArray);
```

Comment: Actually in this case he's just sorting alphabetically, which really seems like it should work +1

Comment: @Scott I'm just sorting strings not dates. This works and I've been using this for a while now.

Comment: Great minds think alike. As usual I should have posted an answer instead of a comment...

Comment: @mplungjan Yes :-) I too prefer clean and simple solutions over difficult to read and maintain over-complexities.

Answer (score 3):

ISO8601 is designed to sort correctly as plain text, so in general, a normal sort will do.

To sort by a specific key of objects in an array, you need to specify a comparison function to the `sort()` method. In many other languages, these are easy to write using the `cmp` function, but JS doesn't have a built in `cmp` function, so I find it easiest to write my own.

```
var myArray = new Array();

myArray[0] = { name:'oldest', date:'2007-01-17T08:00:00Z' }
myArray[1] = { name:'newest', date:'2011-01-28T08:00:00Z' }
myArray[2] = { name:'old',    date:'2009-11-25T08:00:00Z' }

// cmp helper function - built in to many other languages
var cmp = function (a, b) {
    return (a > b) ? 1 : ( (a > b) ? -1 : 0 );
}

myArray.sort(function (a,b) { return cmp(a.date, b.date) });
```

P.s. I would write my array using JSON-like syntax, like this:

```
var myArray = [
    { name:'oldest', date:'2007-01-17T08:00:00Z' },
    { name:'newest', date:'2011-01-28T08:00:00Z' },
    { name:'old',    date:'2009-11-25T08:00:00Z' }
];
```

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/4tUZt/2/

```
$(document).ready(function()
{ 
    var myArray = [ { name:'oldest', date:'2007-01-17T08:00:00Z' },
        { name:'newest', date:'2011-01-28T08:00:00Z' },
        { name:'old',    date:'2009-11-25T08:00:00Z' }];

    console.log( myArray.sort(sortByDate) );        
});

// Stable, ascending sort (use < for descending)
function sortByDate( obj1, obj2 ) {
    return new Date(obj2.date) > new Date(obj1.date) ? 1 : -1;
}
```

​

Comment: older versions of WebKit and Internet Explorer do not support ISO 8601 natively. So this may fail in older browsers.

Comment: How about just sort on string ?

Comment: @scott Thanks good to know, I'm not positive which versions of IE actually support it, I'll double check.

Comment: @mplungjan My immediate reaction was "that won't work"...but in thinking about it I can't think of a counter-example. Perhaps it would work. I suppose it's always safer to stick with the date formatting anyway though...to handle the abbreviated versions, or API's that don't follow the standard strictly

Comment: If the string is consistent it surely beats having to run through hoops to make it work for the browsers that do not like the format

Comment: While this is simpler than Scott's answer, it's still unnecessarily complex.  ISO8601 is [designed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#General_principles) for lexicographical sort, so `'2007-01-17T08:00:00Z' < '2008-01-17T08:00:00Z'  ===  true`.  See @rjmunro answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4tUZt/4/

```
var myArray = new Array();

myArray[0] = { name:'oldest', date: '2007-01-17T08:00:00Z' };
myArray[1] = { name:'newest', date: '2011-01-28T08:00:00Z' };
myArray[2] = { name:'old',    date: '2009-11-25T08:00:00Z' };

var sortFunction = function (a, b) {
  return Date.parse(b.date) - Date.parse(a.date);
};

/* or

var sortFunction = function (a, b) {
  return new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date);
};

*/

console.log(myArray.sort(sortFunction));
```

​

Answer (score 0):

In the instance that you're sorting objects that may be missing a date, and dates may be in different timezones, you'll end up needing something a little more complex:

```js
const deletionDateSortASC = (itemA, itemB) => 
  (+new Date(itemA.deletedAt) || 0) -
  (+new Date(itemB.deletedAt) || 0);

const deletionDateSortDESC = (itemA, itemB) => 
  deletionDateSortASC(itemB, itemA);
```

If you know the dates are all defined and valid, and you know that all the dates are in the same timezone, then you should pick one of the other faster answers. However, if you want date sorting, have one or more of these edge cases, and don't want to have to preprocess the data to clean it up, then I suggest this approach.

I tried to demonstrate in the snippet below how the other answers fail in these edge cases.

```js
const data = [
  {deletedAt: null},
  {deletedAt: '2022-08-24T12:00:00Z'},
  {deletedAt: undefined},
  {deletedAt: '2015-01-01T00:00:00Z'},
  {deletedAt: '2022-08-24T12:00:00-01:00'},
  {deletedAt: '2022-08-24T12:00:00+01:00'},
  {deletedAt: '2022-08-20T12:00:00+01:00'},
  {deletedAt: undefined}
];

const deletionDateSortASC = (itemA, itemB) =>
  (+new Date(itemA.deletedAt) || 0) -
  (+new Date(itemB.deletedAt) || 0);
const deletionDateSortDESC = (itemA, itemB) =>
  deletionDateSortASC(itemB, itemA);

function acceptedAnswerSortASC(a, b) {
  return (a.deletedAt < b.deletedAt) ? -1 : ((a.deletedAt > b.deletedAt) ? 1 : 0);
}
function acceptedAnswerSortDESC(a, b) {
  return acceptedAnswerSortASC(b, a);
}

// Had to modify this solution to avoid the TypeError: a.deletedAt is null
const localeCompareSortASC = (a, b) => (a.deletedAt || '').localeCompare(b.deletedAt);
const localeCompareSortDESC = (a, b) => -(a.deletedAt || '').localeCompare(b.deletedAt);

function simpleDateSubtractionSortASC(a, b) {
  return new Date(a.deletedAt) - new Date(b.deletedAt);
}
function simpleDateSubtractionSortDESC(a, b) {
  return simpleDateSubtractionSortASC(b, a);
}

console.log('Using modified Date subtraction', [...data].sort(deletionDateSortDESC));
console.log('Using accepted answer lexocographical sort', [...data].sort(acceptedAnswerSortDESC));
console.log('Using locale compare lexocographical sort', [...data].sort(localeCompareSortDESC));
console.log('Using simple Date subtraction sort', [...data].sort(simpleDateSubtractionSortDESC));
```