# Sorting a string date array in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, sorting

I'm trying to sort an array of object which contains a date string property.

```
....
62: {dateWatched: "2018-09-12", id: 303, name: "I, Robot", year: "2004", titleType: "Movie", director: "Alex Proyas", …}
63: {dateWatched: "2018-09-12", id: 284, name: "X+Y", year: "2014", titleType: "Movie", director: "Morgan Matthews", …}
64: {dateWatched: "2021-01-17", id: 276, name: "The Ring", year: "2002", titleType: "Movie", director: "Gore Verbinski", …}
65: {dateWatched: "2018-09-15", id: 239, name: "The Intern", year: "2015", titleType: "Movie", director: "Nancy Meyers", …}
66: {dateWatched: "2020-12-22", id: 204, name: "Robot & Frank", year: "2012", titleType: "Movie", director: "Jake Schreier", …}
.....
```

dateWatched property is a yyyy-mm-dd formatted string type. 1-digit month and day fields include 0 as the first character. These codes don't work properly;

```
this.filteredMovies.sort(function(a, b) {
      const arr1 = a.dateWatched.split('-');
      const arr2 = b.dateWatched.split('-');
      const date1 = new Date(parseInt(arr1[0]), parseInt(arr1[1]), parseInt(arr1[2]));
      const date2 = new Date(parseInt(arr2[0]), parseInt(arr2[1]), parseInt(arr2[2]));
      return date1.getTime() - date2.getTime();
    });
```

```
this.filteredMovies.sort(function(a, b) {
      const date1 = a.dateWatched.split('-').join('');
      const date2 = b.dateWatched.split('-').join('');
      return date1 > date2 ? 1 : date1 < date2 ? -1 : 0;
    });
```

Is there a simple and shortest way to do that? I don't want to use a library for this.

Comment: What happens if you just use a normal sort a la `this.filteredMovies.sort(function (a, b) { return a.dateWatched.localeCompare(b.dateWatched); });`?

Comment: @HereticMonkey - re: answer recent dupe - maybe, I answer alot of q's but try to flag dupes. Sometimes they get past me, though looking at my recent history, I don't see a flagged duplicate for localeCompare that I answered. Still, its possible. Interesting that I got downvoted, but none of the others.

Comment: @Kinglish There's a few people around that answer questions first before even looking for dupes. I'm just tired of seeing the same names on answers to dupes that I've marked 100 times before. I understand, there's no gamification incentive for anyone to mark duplicates.

Comment: @hereticmonkey - I hear you. I was less diligent regarding typo and dupe flagging in the beginning. Took me a few callouts before I got with it, and even still a few slip by, like some of the higher scored answers below.

Comment: @Oguz, your date are string in the format yyyy-mm-dd, so you can sort simply as string: `this.filteredMovies.sort(function(a, b) { return a.dateWatched > b.dateWatched ? 1 : a.dateWatched < b.dateWatched ? -1 : 0; }); `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I am missing something, you can just directly convert to `Date` without splitting?

```
this.filteredMovies.sort(function(a, b) {
  return new Date(a.dateWatched) > new Date(b.dateWatched);
});
```

Comment: I tried this at first but I couldn't, maybe I just missed something. It works now, thanks.

Comment: @Taylor, you needn't convert to Date, the dates are in format yyyy-mm-dd.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [string#localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) to compare dates.

```
this.filteredMovies.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.dateWatched.localeCompare(b.dateWatched)
});
```

Comment: Same as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52583894/215552) on the duplicate.