# How can I sort date in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sorting

Considering that I have the below response, which consists of date and time, I want them in sorted format. How can I sort the json of date time in descending format.

let data =

```
[
  {
    "created_at" : "2020-12-01T05:11:08Z",
    "id" : "1"
  },
  {
    "created_at" : "2022-10-10T06:18:08Z",
    "id" : "2"
  },
  {
    "created_at" : "2021-11-12T02:48:08Z",
    "id" : "3"
  },
  ,
  {
    "created_at" : "2021-11-12T02:49:08Z",
    "id" : "4"
  }
]
```

After applying the sorting code, I need the data should look like:

result =

```
[
  {
    "created_at" : "2022-10-10T06:18:08Z",
    "id" : "2"
  },
  {
    "created_at" : "2021-11-12T02:49:08Z",
    "id" : "4"
  },
  {
    "created_at" : "2021-11-12T02:48:08Z",
    "id" : "3"
  },
  {
    "created_at" : "2020-12-01T05:11:08Z",
    "id" : "1"
  }
  
]
```

Comment: The question has already been answered on other posts. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10124053/7670747

Comment: @AtulStha much easer when sorted lexicographically: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12192544