# Issues with Time math in calculating dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date, time

I have a countdown [here](http://donutdev.com/countdown/) which counts down to New Year's fine. But, for some reason the exact same code fails to work [here](http://donutdev.com/countdown/christmas/) when i put in a different date; it is exactly 1 month off.

Why is this happening?

Specifically, here is the code im using to get the days, hours, etc:

```
christmas = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), 12, 25);

seconds = Math.floor((christmas - (new Date()))/1000);
minutes = Math.floor(seconds/60);
hours = Math.floor(minutes/60);
days = Math.floor(hours/24);

hours = hours-(days*24);
minutes = minutes-(days*24*60)-(hours*60);
seconds = seconds-(days*24*60*60)-(hours*60*60)-(minutes*60);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to subtract date/time in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944750/how-to-subtract-date-time-in-javascript)

Comment: I have it completely working for the first link, though why does it fail in the second one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```
> christmas = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), 12, 25);
```

Javascript months are zero indexed:

```
var christmas = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), 11, 25);
```

Comment: Ohhhhh! that explains a lot! Thank you :D