# Subtracting days from a date in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have 2 `<input type="text">` tags and I enter dates in them like this `22-05-2013`

I want to subtract `22-06-2012` from that date

How do I do this?

I've tried this code but it didn't work:

```
function returnDate(nDays){
  var now = new Date();
  var dayOfTheWeek = now.getDay();
  now.setTime(now.getTime() - nDays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

  alert(now);  // returns current date
  alert(now.getFullYear() + "/"+(now.getMonth()+1)+"/"+now.getDate()) // returns new calculated date
}
```

So I need the difference between `22-05-2013` and `22-06-2012`

Comment: Duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224834/get-difference-between-2-dates-in-javascript/15289883#15289883

Comment: And of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944750/how-to-subtract-date-time-in-javascript, which is also a duplicate. Search before asking.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do it would be to use [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/). It has fantastic support for dates.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you could subtract 2 [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) objects and this will return the number of milliseconds between them. For example:

```
var date1 = new Date('2013-06-22 01:00:00');
var date2 = new Date('2013-06-22 01:00:01');

var result = date2 - date1;
alert(result); // shows 1000 which is 1 second
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

`new Date(mydate1 - mydate2).getDay() ;`

This will give you the number of days.

I would suggest you use **Date.js** though, which would be even simpler.