# How can i calculate time between hours?

Tags: javascript, date, math

I have two strings like

```
var x = "22:10";
var y = "23:15";
```

How can i calculate using javascript the time is remaining to x get into y?

in this case would be

```
var final = "01:05"
```

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? What I would do is convert them both to seconds -> calculate the difference -> converting the difference to hours.

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944750/how-to-subtract-date-time-in-javascript).

Comment: @JeroenJK I have another method :)

Comment: Do you need to allow for times that span midnight? (E.g., if `y` was `"03:15"`?)

Comment: I may found real good solution at this question that @eebbesen posted here

[link](http://jsfiddle.net/zANNt/1/)

Comment: Yes @nnnnnn i should care about times that span midnight :P

Comment: The method I posted before, but first checking if `var y` is smaller than `var x`. If that's the case then you just take the time of `var x` (in seconds) to 24:00 in seconds + the time of `var y` (in seconds). EDIT:: Oh wait, you could also just use minutes instead of seconds! :D

Comment: Would it ever need to be more than 24 hours (e.g. three days away)?

Comment: Are you going to accept an answer..?

Answer (score 4):

@Man of Snow solution is simple and I think it works well, but if you will need more complex example for working with dates you can review my code:

```
var x = "22:10";
var y = "23:15";

function createDate(v) {
    var date = new Date(),
        va = v.split(':');

    date.setHours(va[0]);
    date.setMinutes(va[1]);

    return date;
}

function getDiff(x, y) {
    var date1 = createDate(x),
        date2 = createDate(y);

    var result = new Date();
    result.setTime(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());

    var hours = result.getUTCHours().toString(),
        minutes = result.getUTCMinutes().toString();

    if (hours.length == 1) {
        hours = '0' + hours;
    }

    if (minutes.length == 1) {
        minutes = '0' + minutes;
    }

    return hours + ':' + minutes;
}

var diff = getDiff(x, y);

alert(diff);
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/USwuX/1/)

Comment: Thats a nice solution @Filip Górny its seems to be working just fine for me :)

Comment: It logs `02:05`. Shouldn't it be `01:05`?

Comment: That is why I added 

result.setHours(result.getHours()-1);

I tested it in Chrome and the result is 01:05

Comment: **+1** We need days, right? ;) (hint, hint!  Add support for days!  Only showing up to 12 hours not good!)

Comment: -1 because using `.setHours(result.getHours()-1)` instead of UTC. This `-1` only works in your time zone

Answer (score 1):

### Where's the code?

Here's the code!

```
var x = "22:10";
var y = "23:15";

var xTotal = parseInt(x.split(':')[0] * 60) + parseInt(x.split(':')[1]);
var yTotal = parseInt(y.split(':')[0] * 60) + parseInt(y.split(':')[1]);
var total = yTotal - xTotal;

var minutes = Math.floor(total / 60);
var seconds = total - minutes * 60;

if(seconds.toString().length == 1)
{
    seconds = seconds.toString();
    seconds = '0' + seconds;
}

var final = minutes.toString() + ':' + seconds.toString();
console.log(final);
```

which logs 1:05 (as you can see will also work with minutes).

### How's it work?

I'm glad you asked, Ben.  Well, it converts the first and second part around the colon to seconds (minutes * 40), of course `parseInt`, because they're **Strings!**  Anyways, it now divides *that* number's rounded state (`Math.floor()` for you programmers at home) by **60** to get the amount of minutes.  And you know what it does then, Ben?

(Ben:  Nope, but I wish it did what I thought.)

I'm glad you say so, Ben!  Well, here's what it does *then:*  It actually **takes** that total number of seconds and **subtracts** it by the number of minutes * 60, and what does it do now?  Well, I'll tell you, Ben!  It actually converts it into a *string!*  Minutes, a colon, then *seconds!*  How cool's that?

(Ben:  Great, we'll be in touch.  Next?)

### I'm too lazy to Copy/Paste this.  Where's the Fiddle?

[It's right over here, Ben! (which alerts instead of logs)](http://jsfiddle.net/ngjKm/2/)

...who's Ben???

Comment: I didn't downvote, but doesn't this output `"1:5"`? Also, remember that `y` could be after midnight...

Comment: @nnnnnn Edited, hope it gets an upvote now to pay for the downvote

Comment: `final` isn't a reserved word in ES5 (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words#In_ECMAScript_5)

Comment: The fiddle is alerting "45:25" when the answer _should_ be "1:05".

Comment: @nnnnnn Yeah, I have a problem with rushing through questions.  I've edited my answer so it now displays '1:05'.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
function padding(str, len, char) {
    return (Array(len).join(char)+str).substr(-len);
}

var x = "22:10",
    y = "23:15",
    day = "Sun Jan 05 2014 ", // or whatever
    final = new Date(new Date(day+y)-new Date(day+x));
final = padding(final.getUTCHours(), 2, 0) + ':' + padding(final.getUTCMinutes(), 2, 0);
```

Comment: +1 I think this is much more professional solution than mine. Thanks, I learned something new :-)