# How to calculate number of hours after night start

Tags: javascript, math

I have current hour and I want to count how many hours have passed since the start of the night. For example night started at 19:00 and current hour is 4:00, how can I calculate this (especially it must work in both cases e.g. 23:00 and 4:00)? I only have this:

```
now = new Date(),
now = now.getHours();
night_start = 19;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944750/how-to-subtract-date-time-in-javascript

Comment: `var diff = night_start >= now ? ((24-night_start) + now) : now - night_start`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can doit like this

```
now = new Date(),
now = now.getHours();
night_start = 19;

var hours = ((now - night_start)<0?24:0)+( (now - night_start));
```