# Compare dates in javascript: IE 8 Exception

Tags: javascript, date, internet-explorer-8

I have tried the following code to compare two dates

```
    //the following check validates that the date is entered in the right format and it works
    if(s_period=="" || !date_format.exec(s_period))
    {
            alert("Please enter start date as YYYY-MM-DD");
            return false;
    }

    //next, i want to check if s_period is greater than '2013-06-30'
     if((new Date(s_period).getTime()) < (new Date("2013-07-01").getTime()))
     {
            alert("Stat available from 2013-07-01");
            return false;

      }
```

The above alert for choosing a date after 2013-06-30 gets invoked in Firefox but, NOT on IE8. Can someone suggest the additional code I need to add to make it work across all browser version?
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944750/how-to-subtract-date-time-in-javascript

Comment: Is this your entire program?

Comment: What is date_form.exec?

Comment: date_format=/^(\d{4})\-(\d{2})\-(\d{2})$/. Compares the date against the regular expression date_format

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/ughcnnom/

Comment: It appears the .getTime() or new Date(s_period_.getTime() is not working. Because, if I include an else statement after the last if to alert s_period, I do get the right user input value. Am I missing any java library for Date function to work??

Comment: Alright, it is actually an issue with IE8 as it works fine on firefox. Any suggestion on what changes are needed in the code to make it compatible with IE8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Date.parse http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/k4w173wk(v=vs.94).aspx

e.g.

```
if((Date.parse(s_period)) < (Date.parse("2013-07-01")))
```

Comment: Thanks for showing me that function. However, it still does not work on IE8. The function works on Firefox b/c I tried the following: d_s_period = Date.parse("2013-01-01");
        document.write(d_s_period); It prints NaN in IE 8 but, 1356998400000 on Firefox

Comment: Change the date format to '2013/01/01' (use / instead of -)