# Convert number of days into years, months, days

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two date pickers that calculates the number of days there are between the two dates. At the moment I'm outputting the number of days (see code below) which is kind of meaningless. I want to output that number in years, months, days. How can I do that?

E.g So 01/01/14 to 01/02/15 = 397 days which then becomes 1 year(s), 1 month(s), 1 day(s)

```
var diff = endDate - startDate;
dayCount = diff / ( 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000 ); // secs * mins * hours * milliseconds
dayCount = Math.round( dayCount ) + this.options.countAdjust;
return dayCount;
```

Comment: @George how the F it relates to the question ? `prettyDate("2008-01-14T22:24:17Z") // => "2 weeks ago"`

Comment: **How it is 1 month ?????**  it is 0 month ! (M/d/y)

Comment: Most users use the standard d/m/y format Royi

Comment: @Kloar so the day should be 0 then !

Comment: @RoyiNamir Yes, it's probably a typo

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to calculate date difference in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763327/how-to-calculate-date-difference-in-javascript)

Comment: @ArindamNayak no. look at the values in the dup. it's not right

Comment: @RoyiNamir, sorry i did not get you, which values you are referring?

Comment: @ArindamNayak Jut run the code there. ( in the dups)  - not the ones with library

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*You have a bug in your calculation :
it's 0 month.
And if you mean d/m/y then
`1 year, 1 month, and 0 day old.`*

you said  *between the two dates* ( not include) - [look here](http://www.timeanddate.com/date/durationresult.html?d1=1&m1=1&y1=2014&d2=1&m2=2&y2=2015)

**Anyway** here is the right code which include actually count each month - how many days it has ! ( leap year consideration):

notice :

I instantiated it as d/m/yyy. feel free to send right pattern in :

`alert(getAge(  new Date(1978,11,22),new Date()))`

```js
function getAge(date_1, date_2)
{
  
//convert to UTC
var date2_UTC = new Date(Date.UTC(date_2.getUTCFullYear(), date_2.getUTCMonth(), date_2.getUTCDate()));
var date1_UTC = new Date(Date.UTC(date_1.getUTCFullYear(), date_1.getUTCMonth(), date_1.getUTCDate()));


var yAppendix, mAppendix, dAppendix;


//--------------------------------------------------------------
var days = date2_UTC.getDate() - date1_UTC.getDate();
if (days < 0)
{

    date2_UTC.setMonth(date2_UTC.getMonth() - 1);
    days += DaysInMonth(date2_UTC);
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------
var months = date2_UTC.getMonth() - date1_UTC.getMonth();
if (months < 0)
{
    date2_UTC.setFullYear(date2_UTC.getFullYear() - 1);
    months += 12;
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------
var years = date2_UTC.getFullYear() - date1_UTC.getFullYear();




if (years > 1) yAppendix = " years";
else yAppendix = " year";
if (months > 1) mAppendix = " months";
else mAppendix = " month";
if (days > 1) dAppendix = " days";
else dAppendix = " day";


return years + yAppendix + ", " + months + mAppendix + ", and " + days + dAppendix + " old.";
}


function DaysInMonth(date2_UTC)
{
var monthStart = new Date(date2_UTC.getFullYear(), date2_UTC.getMonth(), 1);
var monthEnd = new Date(date2_UTC.getFullYear(), date2_UTC.getMonth() + 1, 1);
var monthLength = (monthEnd - monthStart) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
return monthLength;
}


alert(getAge(new Date(1978, 11, 22), new Date()))
```

Comment: Note that the "convert to UTC" expression is misleading. ECMAScript Dates **are** UTC, no conversion required. The expression is equivalent to `date2.setUTCHours(0,0,0,0)`. The *DaysInMonth* function is unnecessarily complex ([*Get number days in a specified month*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/315760/what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-the-number-of-days-in-a-month-with-javascript)).

Comment: this logic will not yield the accurate output because of miscalculated `getUTCMonth()` and `getMonth()` it must be added by `+1` to make it right since it is counted as index from `0(jan) to 11(dec)`.

Comment: @robg what exactly does setutchours 0 0 0 0 0 do ? Didnt find that in the docs (0 values)

Comment: *setUTCHours* sets the UTC time to 00:00:00.000, see [*§ 20.3.4.30 Date.prototype.setUTCHours ( hour \[ , min \[ , sec \[ , ms \] \] \] )*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/).

Comment: @Robg that's not what i meant.  Why do you say that convert to utc is not required?  And how's  does setutchoyrs reolves that?

Comment: Dates **are** UTC, they don't have a timezone. The code `var date2_UTC = new Date(Date.UTC(date_2.getUTCFullYear(), date_2.getUTCMonth(), date_2.getUTCDate()));` is identical to `var date2_UTC = new Date(date_2); date2_UTC.setUTCHours(0,0,0,0)`. Both create a "copy" of the original date with the UTC time set to 00:00:00.000, but one is a lot less code.

Comment: ```getUTCFullYear()``` resulted in 'getutcfullyear is not a function'. Changed it to ```getfullyear()```

Answer (score 1):

You can use link shown below , it has more detailed explanation. [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Arindamnayak/xskmf8y9/3/) The detailed code is -

```
var DateDiff = {

    inDays: function(d1, d2) {
        var t2 = d2.getTime();
        var t1 = d1.getTime();

        return parseInt((t2-t1)/(24*3600*1000));
    },

    inWeeks: function(d1, d2) {
        var t2 = d2.getTime();
        var t1 = d1.getTime();

        return parseInt((t2-t1)/(24*3600*1000*7));
    },

    inMonths: function(d1, d2) {
        var d1Y = d1.getFullYear();
        var d2Y = d2.getFullYear();
        var d1M = d1.getMonth();
        var d2M = d2.getMonth();

        return (d2M+12*d2Y)-(d1M+12*d1Y);
    },

    inYears: function(d1, d2) {
        return d2.getFullYear()-d1.getFullYear();
    }
}


var d1 = new Date("01/01/14");
var d2 = new Date("01/02/15");
var months= DateDiff.inYears(d1, d2)*12 ;
var month = DateDiff.inMonths(d1, d2) - months;
var days = DateDiff.inYears(d1, d2)*365;
var dy = DateDiff.inDays(d1, d2) - days;
alert(DateDiff.inYears(d1, d2) + " Year " + month + " Month "+ dy + " Days");
```

[Link](http://ditio.net/2010/05/02/javascript-date-difference-calculation/)

Comment: So if it makes a duplicate post, flag the question as a duplicate, it is useless to post an answer like that

Comment: @NicolasR , done with flagging, I have never realized that, Thanks!

Comment: that's not what he wants  .look at the comments to sean

Comment: @RoyiNamir , i have used OP's input values, so for particular that input, result is 1,1,1 , also OP told that too! , or am i  missing anything?

Comment: OP has mistake! dont need to be a genius to see that he's wrong

Comment: @RoyiNamir , then i am still not sure, what need to be done to help OP, because, so far i have created a function to get day, month, year, and that is what needed.

Comment: look : pure caltulation of days  : ((new Date(2015,1,1))-(new Date(2014,0,1))) /(1000*60*60*24) ----> 396 days and not 397 like he said. now how do you convert this to years ?  a year doesnt contain exactly 365 days ! . so look at my code to see how you subtract each section and get to the right result ( by high resiolution of how many days in each month ! - including leap years).... **look at my code**

Comment: run this also http://www.timeanddate.com/date/durationresult.html?d1=1&m1=1&y1=2014&d2=1&m2=2&y2=2015

Answer (score 1):

```
function parseDays (value) {
    const YEAR = 365, MONTH = 30, WEEK = 7;
    let year, months, week, days;
         
    year = value >= YEAR ? Math.floor(value / YEAR) : 0;
    value = year ? value - (year * YEAR) : value;
        
    months = value >= MONTH ? Math.floor((value % YEAR) / MONTH) : 0;
    value = months ? value - (months * MONTH) : value;
        
    week = value >= WEEK ? Math.floor((value % YEAR) / WEEK) : 0;
    value = week ? value - (week * WEEK) : value;
        
    days = value < WEEK ? Math.floor((value % YEAR) % WEEK) : 0;
        
    console.log(`years=${year},months=${months},weeks=${week},days=${days}`);     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered several times befoore: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/17733753/550198

You can modify the following method quite easily to suit your purposes:

```
today = new Date()
past = new Date(2010,05,01) // remember this is equivalent to 06 01 2010
//dates in js are counted from 0, so 05 is june

function calcDate(date1,date2) {
    var diff = Math.floor(date1.getTime() - date2.getTime());
    var day = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

    var days = Math.floor(diff/day);
    var months = Math.floor(days/31);
    var years = Math.floor(months/12);

    var message = date2.toDateString();
    message += " was "
    message += days + " days " 
    message += months + " months "
    message += years + " years ago \n"

    return message
    }


a = calcDate(today,past)
console.log(a) // returns Tue Jun 01 2010 was 1143 days 36 months 3 years ago
```

Comment: that's not what he wants

Comment: @RoyiNamir It is precisely what he asked for. What part of it does not answer the question?

Comment: running your code : `Tue Jun 01 2010 was 1584 days 51 months 4 years ago ` . but he wants the reminders in each part ! not the translation to each time section !

Comment: 51 month should add 4 years (51 /12) ! look at my solution

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the difference between two dates, in milliseconds

```
var diff = Math.abs(date1 - date2);
```

In your example, it'd be

```
var diff = Math.abs(new Date() - compareDate);
```

You need to make sure that compareDate is a valid Date object.

Something like this will probably work for you

```
var diff = Math.abs(new Date() - new Date(dateStr.replace(/-/g,'/')));
```

i.e. turning "2011-02-07 15:13:06" into new Date('2011/02/07 15:13:06'), which is a format the Date constructor can comprehend.

[Answer Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944750/how-to-subtract-date-time-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

When you want to get the year and month between two date:

```
     var dateFrom = '2017-08-10'; 
     var dateTo ='2019-04-23';
     var date1 = new Date(dateFrom);
     var date2 = new Date(dateTo);
     var diff=0;
     var month=31;
     var days=1000*60*60*24;
     diff=date2-date1; 
     var day=(Math.floor(diff/days));   
     var years = (Math.floor(day/365));
     var months = Math.round(day % 365)/month;
    document.write(years+"year-"+months);
```

Comment: when you want to get the year and month between two date.