# What does the colon operator do in this context?

Tags: javascript

I was looking at piece of code on [How to subtract date/time in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944750/how-to-subtract-date-time-in-javascript) which is like

```
Date.prototype.diffDays = function (date: Date): number {

    var utcThis = Date.UTC(this.getFullYear(), this.getMonth(), this.getDate(), this.getHours(), this.getMinutes(), this.getSeconds(), this.getMilliseconds());
    var utcOther = Date.UTC(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate(), date.getHours(), date.getMinutes(), date.getSeconds(), date.getMilliseconds());

    return (utcThis - utcOther) / 86400000;
};
```

and I'm wondering what the `(date: Date): number` means since I've never seen anything like that and I know this isn't like ECA6 or whatever since the post was made in 2011

Comment: those are type annotations.

Comment: This syntax also appears in ActionScript, also an ECMAScript derivative.

Comment: Is ActionScript still alive?

Comment: What was the name of the file where you found that?

Comment: @torazaburo The OP found it in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14779469/2680216) (as stated in the question).

Answer (score 3):

That's TypeScript. It's a function that accepts a parameter of type `date` and returns a `number`

Answer (score 3):

This is typescript (http://www.typescriptlang.org/), a superset of javascript that adds typing to variables, not pure javascript.