# How do I subtract two dates?

Tags: javascript

I have a date stored in a database as a string. It looks like this: 
Tue Aug 23 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (CDT)

I basically want to tell if today's date is before or after the date in the database.

The code below should sort of explain what I want. The problem is that after the difference variable doesn't return a number variable, which is what I need.

```
var expire = value.vaccines;
var today = new Date();
var difference = today-expire;

if(difference <= 0){
    $(element).css({"color": "#0040ff"});
}
```

Any ideas on how to subtract these two dates and get a number value?

Comment: How are you getting 'vaccines'?

Comment: Probably duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944750/how-to-subtract-date-time-in-javascript

Comment: @Nerlin Or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript), assuming `value.vaccines` has been constructed correctly.

Comment: @saby vaccines is a column in the database.

Comment: *"The problem is that after the difference variable doesn't return a number variable, which is what I need."* What type is the value of `difference` instead?

Comment: @FelixKling I get NaN

Answer (score 0):

You can just you can calculate the difference between the two `Date` objects and get the absolute value with [Math.abs()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs):

```
var today = new Date(),
    expire = value.vaccines,
    difference = Math.abs(today - expire); // difference in milliseconds

if (difference <= 0) {
    $(element).css({
        "color": "#0040ff"
    });
}
```

Check that `expire` is a valid `Date` object.

Comment: Expire and today both look like this: Tue Aug 23 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (CDT)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both your objects are `Date`

Although you only require the returned value in milliseconds, I've added the extra step of formatting the value.

```
Math.floor((today - expire) / (1000*60*60*24))
```

Taken from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763327/how-to-calculate-date-difference-in-javascript)