# How to check if the date having more than one year from current year

Tags: javascript

I am trying to check if the date i.e. (07/02/2018 ) is more than year from current date and  if the date i.e. (07/02/2018 ) is less than year from current date using JavaScript tried with following code

```
var x = new Date('JUN-2016');
var y = new Date('MAY-2016');
console.log(+x < +y);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not very clear to me but this may help you:

```js
var now = new Date();
var then = new Date('07/02/2018');
var diffInDays = Math.round((then-now) / (1000*60*60*24));

console.log('then is', diffInDays, 'days more than now.');
```

*Note: If `diffInDays` is a positive number then the `then` is more than `now`, otherwise it's less.*

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add `1000*60*60*24*365` milliseconds to your first date and compare it to your second date :

```js
var x = new Date('APR-2015');
var y = new Date('MAY-2016');

console.log(+x + 1000*60*60*24*365 < +y);

var x2 = new Date('SEP-2015');

console.log(+x2 + 1000*60*60*24*365 < +y);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the year with the `getFullYear()`method ([Date doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)).

```
let x = new Date();
let y = new Date();

x_year = x.getFullYear();
y_year = y.getFullYear();

// The you just have to compare the year
```

Comment: So, for you January 2015 is one year away from December 2014 ?

Comment: Oh okay I didn't understand well, you can do that and also compare the month, it will give you the exact difference. But Zenoo's answer looks better.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it, although I'd be surprised if there wasn't a better way:

```js
var x = new Date();
x = x.setFullYear(x.getFullYear() + 1);
x = new Date(x);
var y = (new Date('2018-04-08'));
var z = (new Date('2019-04-08'));

if (y < x) {
    console.log('Y is less than a year from now');
} else {
    console.log('Y is more or exactly a year from now');
}

if (z < x) {
    console.log('Z is less than a year from now');
} else {
    console.log('Z is more or exactly a year from now');
}
```

Comment: this is similar but can i check if the two dates y and z has more than year and less than year

Comment: If I understand you correctly, yes. Just do lines 2 and 3 to whatever date you want to add a year to, then compare that to the other date.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear this is based on my assumption.
I am assuming that you need to check if the given date is one year ahead of the current date.

```js
var x = new Date('1, 1, 2018');
var today = new Date();
var time = Math.abs(today.getTime() - x.getTime());
var days = Math.ceil(time / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
alert("There is a difference of " + days + " days between today and the given date");
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want to know if some arbitrary date is less or more than a year from current date.

We can get a the value for a year this way:

`var a_year = Math.abs(new Date('01-01-2018'.replace(/-/g,'/')) - new Date('01-01-2017'.replace(/-/g,'/')));`

Then we set two date tests:

`var test1 = '01-01-2018';`

`var test2 = '01-01-2015';`

Calculate the diffs:

`var diff1 = Math.abs(new Date() - new Date(test1.replace(/-/g,'/')));`
`var diff2 = Math.abs(new Date() - new Date(test2.replace(/-/g,'/')));`

Then you can log the results for testing:

`console.log(diff1 > a_year)`
`console.log(diff1 < a_year)`
`console.log(diff2 > a_year)`
`console.log(diff2 < a_year)`

Credits to [David Hedlund's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/133802/david-hedlund) answer on [How to subtract date/time in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944750/how-to-subtract-date-time-in-javascript)