# Not exiting while loop in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a localhost website where I have a "start" button which triggers the follow function:

```
function startGame(){
    startTime = new Date().getTime();
    currentTime = new Date().getTime();
    while((currentTime-startTime)<2000){
        document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = 'test1'
        if(allyClicked){
            allyTrack += 1;
            allyString.append(allyTrack.toString())
            allyClicked = false;
        } else if(scaleClicked){
            scaleTrack += 1;
            scaleString.append(scaleTrack.toString())
            scaleClicked = false;
        } else if(enemyClicked){
            enemyTrack += 1;
            enemyString.append(enemyTrack.toString())
            enemyClicked = false;
        } else{
            allyString.append(allyTrack.toString())
            scaleString.append(scaleTrack.toString())
            enemyString.append(enemyTrack.toString())               
        }
        currentTime = new Date().getTime();
    }
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = 'test2';
    document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = allyString + '\n' + scaleString + '\n' + enemyString;
}
```

The issue I seem to be having is that although I set a time limit of 2000 milliseconds, it does not leave the loop. (and change "test1" to "test2")  Client-Server communication is confusing to me because this is my first attempt at a website, so I apologize if I'm missing something dumb.

**Edited:**

```
function startGame(){
            var startTime = new Date().getTime();
            //var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
            while(true){
                document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = 'test1';
                if(allyClicked){
                    allyTrack += 1;
                    allyString.append(allyTrack.toString())
                    allyClicked = false;
                }
                else if(scaleClicked){
                    scaleTrack += 1;
                    scaleString.append(scaleTrack.toString())
                    scaleClicked = false;
                }
                else if(enemyClicked){
                    enemyTrack += 1;
                    enemyString.append(enemyTrack.toString())
                    enemyClicked = false;
                }
                else{
                    allyString.append(allyTrack.toString())
                    scaleString.append(scaleTrack.toString())
                    enemyString.append(enemyTrack.toString())               
                }
                //currentTime = new Date().getTime();

                if((Math.abs(new Date().getTime() - startTime))>2000){
                    break;
                }
            }
            document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = 'test2';
            document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = allyString + '\n' + scaleString + '\n' + enemyString;
        }
```

Still not printing the "test2".  I must still be missing something.

Comment: use `break;` to leave the loop

Comment: check this out - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944750/how-to-subtract-date-time-in-javascript

Comment: Any console errors? As per wallet616 below your loop code does work (without any of your variables) - https://jsfiddle.net/89wfu2vp/8/ - check into setTimeout.

Comment: How do you see console errors for localhost?  That would definitely help me debug.

Comment: Where do you set `allyClicked` ?

Comment: In another function which runs when a button is clicked.  I want to make it so that it can be pressed multiple times.

Comment: @riley could you show that code please?

Answer (score -1):

In your while loop condition, have you tried switching the order? Like so:

```
while (startTime - currentTime < 2000) {
  // code goes here
}
```

Comment: That would exit immediately?